# Why is install_name_tool and otool necessary for Mach-O libraries in Mac Os X?

Tags: macos, mach-o, otool, install-name-tool

I am developing a Cocoa Application using the latest version of Xcode 4, I want to link dynamic libraries to my project (`dylibs`).

I read somewhere that adding the libraries in my project was not enough as I have to run `install_name_tool` and `otool` to make my project use the libraries that were bundled in my project.

I have read the manual pages for `install_name_tool`, but I do not understand WHY I have to do this.

How do libraries work? Especially interested in the part where the application and the libraries have paths that point to specific places in my machine, like `/usr/local/lib/mylibrary.dylib` when running `otool -L`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Apple has several ways of locating shared libraries:

1. `@executable_path` : relative to the main executable
2. `@loader_path`  : relative to the referring binary
3. `@rpath` : relative to any of a list of paths.

`@rpath` is the most recent addition, introduced in OS X 10.5.

If for instance you want to have your executable in `Contents/MacOS` and libraries in `Contents/Libraries` you could do the following:

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/Libraries/lib_this.dylib   builddir/lib_this.dylib
```

and in the top-level executable set `rpath` with:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath @loader_path/..  myexecutable
```

and:

```
install_name_tool -change builddir/lib_this.dylib @rpath/Libraries/lib_this.dylib myexecutable
```

Note: that the first path after `-change` must match exactly what is currently in the binary.

If you get lost `otool -l -v myexecutable` will tell you what load commands exactly are currently in the executable.

See `man dyld` and `man install_name_tool` for more information.

Comment: `otool -L` is also helpful to display the names and shared libraries (that you might want to change with `install_name_tool`.

Comment: Note: install_name_tool fails silently; always double check that it actually did what you told it to do (using 'otool -L <path_to_dylib>'.

Comment: It seems that the attributes in a dylib don't really matter. They are used only when linking an executable to the dylib to copy the attributes from the dylib to the executable.
For the case when you already have an executable linked to a dylib but you need to change the paths, then it's enough to edit only the executable to set LC_LOAD_DYLIB and, optionally, LC_RPATH. The second is needed only if the first one has @rpath in it.

Comment: The part that saved me was: "Note: that the first path after `-change` must match exactly what is currently in the binary." I hadn't realized that it was necessary to include the full path as it appears in the `otool -L` dump. in my case that path was `/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib` and it wasn't working if I just used `libcrypto.1.1.dylib` for that parameter.

Answer (score 12):

There is also a GUI tool named MacDependency which will expose all dependent libraries (https://github.com/kwin/macdependency/).