# dylib cannot load libstd when compiled in a workspace

Tags: python, macos, rust, dylib, rust-cargo

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Cargo.toml
my_script.py
my_lib:
    - Cargo.toml
    - src
my_bin:
    - Cargo.toml
    - src
```

Where:

- `my_lib` is a Rust library with `crate-type = ["dylib"]`
- `my_bin` is a Rust binary application using `my_lib`
- `my_script.py` is a Python 3 script that also uses `my_lib`

The root `Cargo.toml` contains a basic workspace declaration:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "my_lib",
    "my_bin"
]
```

Everything works properly if I execute `cargo build` and `cargo run -p my_bin`. The problem comes with the Python script.

In this script, I load the `my_lib` lib file using the following code:

```py
from ctypes import cdll
from sys import platform

if platform == 'darwin':
    prefix = 'lib'
    ext = 'dylib'
elif platform == 'win32':
    prefix = ''
    ext = 'dll'
else:
    prefix = 'lib'
    ext = 'so'

# Working path:
# lib_path = './my_lib/target/debug/{}my_lib.{}'.format(prefix, ext)

# Buggy "Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-d00eaa6834e55536.dylib" path:
lib_path = './target/debug/{}my_lib.{}'.format(prefix, ext)

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
my_func = lib.my_func
my_func()
```

If I use the library file from the *library directory* (`./my_lib/target/...`), the script has no problem loading the library and executing its functions.

But if I use the library file from the *workspace directory* (`./target/...`) I get the following error when trying to load the library:

```
OSError: dlopen(./target/debug/libpeglrs.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-d00eaa6834e55536.dylib
```

In the same fashion, trying to execute `my_bin` directly from the workspace target directory yields the same error (even though `cargo run -p my_bin` work flawlessly).

Using the software "Dependency Walker", I found that the `my_lib` library cannot find the Rust `libstd` library (has the previous error message explain).

Manually exporting the path that contains the Rust toolchain library into the environment `PATH` fixes the issue. This is however far from ideal and not portable. I also don't understand why this issue is only occurring *when using the **workspace** target*.

So, why can't the workspace target find rust's `libstd` when each project target can? Is there a way to fix this issue that wouldn't require to find the toolchain path and modify an environment variable?

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/932 
And running `rustup run beta python3 editor.py` does work, but still doesn't explain why only the workspace is buggy.

Comment: Have you tried building the dynamic library with `cdylib`?

Comment: It's working but I lose the ability to use the lib directly has a dependency in the binary project (since its losing the rust specific info). It would mean that I would have to make ffi against my own Rust lib. Not ideal :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dynamic linking is not easy sometimes. The error message `Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-d00eaa6834e55536.dylib` is pretty clear. You have a problem with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (macOS).

### TL;DR

Your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't contain Rust libraries path. Put following into your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
export RUST_SRC_PATH="$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

### Explanation

I followed your project structure except one thing - I removed `_` (`my_bin` -> `mybin`, ...).

### `cargo run --bin mybin` vs `target/debug/mybin`

As a first thing, check what `otool -L target/debug/mybin` says:

```
target/debug/mybin:
    /Users/robertvojta/Work/bar/target/debug/deps/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Notice the `@rpath`. If you don't know what it is, I'd recommend to read Mike Ash posts:

- [Friday Q&A 2009-11-06: Linking and Install Names](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html)
- [Friday Q&A 2012-11-09: dyld: Dynamic Linking On OS X](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-09-dyld-dynamic-linking-on-os-x.html)

Also run `man dlopen` and read the `SEARCHING` section. It's pretty long to copy & paste it here, so, just the first sentence:

> dlopen() searches for a compatible Mach-O file in the directories specified by a set of environment variables and the process's current working directory.

You'll learn about `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other environment variables.

In your shell, what's the output of `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` command? I assume it's empty / does not contain Rust libraries path.

Add following lines to your `mybin:main.rs` ...

```
println!(
    "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH={}",
    std::env::var("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH").unwrap_or("N/A".to_string())
);
```

... and run `cargo run --bin mybin`. You should see something like this:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib
```

`cargo run` injects this environment variable for you.

From where you can get the right value? Run `rustc --print sysroot` and append `/lib` to the output.

If you'd like to run `mybin` directly (without `cargo`), you can do it in this way:

```sh
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" target/debug/mybin
```

### Python script

Add similar lines to your `run.py` script:

```py
import os
print('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: {}'.format(os.environ.get('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'N/A')))
```

If it prints `N/A`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set. You can fix this in a similar way:

```sh
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(rustc --print sysroot)/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" python run.py
```

#### macOS & System Integrity Protection

Be aware that you can't use system Python for this ...

```sh
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib:
$ /usr/bin/python run.py
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: N/A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 21, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(./target/debug/libmylib.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/robertvojta/Work/bar/target/debug/libmylib.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

... but you can use one installed via `brew` for example ...

```sh
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/robertvojta/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib:
$ /usr/local/bin/python run.py
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: /Users/robertvojta/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib:
```

The reason is SIP. SIP was introduced in El Capitan and it can be in your way. You can experience stuff like:

```sh
$ env | grep DYLD
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/robertvojta/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib:
```

Here's the [SIP description](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) page. SIP protects folders like `/usr`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, but it doesn't protect `/usr/local` for example.

What does it mean? SIP does lot of things, but one of them is trashing `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` value. Shebang lines like ...

- `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- `#!/usr/bin/python`

... wont work for you. You have to use Python interpreter, which is not installed in system (& protected) folders. Install one via `brew`, install Anaconda, ...

SIP can be disabled, but **DON'T** do this.

Another way how to fix this is to replace `@rpath` in your `mylib` with a full path via `install_name_tool` (`man install_name_tool`). More info in [Why is install_name_tool and otool necessary for Mach-O libraries in Mac Os X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263256/why-is-install-name-tool-and-otool-necessary-for-mach-o-libraries-in-mac-os-x).

Example:

```sh
$ otool -L target/debug/mybin
target/debug/mybin:
    /Users/robertvojta/Work/bar/target/debug/deps/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$ install_name_tool -change @rpath/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib /Users/robertvojta/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib target/debug/libmylib.dylib
$ otool -L target/debug/libmylib.dylib
target/debug/libmylib.dylib:
    /Users/robertvojta/Work/bar/target/debug/deps/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /Users/robertvojta/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-d4fbe66ddea5f3ce.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
$ /usr/bin/python run.py
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: N/A
Hallo
```

As you can see, there's no `@rpath` now, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set, but it works (`Hallo` is printed via `hallo` function from `libmylib.dylib`) with system Python interpreter.

Be aware of one thing - macOS dynamic libraries behave differently when compared to Linux for example.

If you do not want to mess with it, you can change `mylib` `crate-type` to `["rlib", "cdylib"]`, but that's not what you probably want.