# PAServer 22 is not working in Mac Monterey, it use dylib that link with framework Python 2.7 and not exist in /System/library/Frameworks of Monterey

Tags: python, delphi, macos-monterey, paserver

I’m download the lastest version of Delphi 11.1 and all is Ok, but when I try to debug project in MAC Monterey 12.3.1 using PAServer 22, I have an error in PAServer Terminal window, it said that Framework Python can’t be found in System/library/Frameworks/.., I install Python 2.7 but it’s not installed in System/... is installed in Library/... and PaServer can’t find it.
Have you any Solutions for that problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I notice the [requirements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Running_the_Platform_Assistant_on_a_Mac#M1_Debugging) say: The PAServer uses LLDB on macOS 64-bit (ARM), which requires Python 3.9.

Comment: The problem is with macOS 64-bits(x86_64) and with (ARM), the problem is in dinamic librarys that use PAServer that have inside fixed references to /System/Library/Frameworks/... of Python 2.7 Framework and in MAC Monterey this path not exits. If you install Python 2.7 the Framework is installed in /Library/Frameworks/... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have the solution, use:

sudo install_name_tool -change '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python liblldb.3.8.0.dylib

I change the dylib that crash, with new path for Python.

Comment: It probably works judging from a description of how install_name_tool works that I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263735/903783

Comment: ...however when you run it (having installed Python 2.7.8 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18-macosx10.9.pkg) it says "can't open file: liblldb.3.8.0.dylib (No such file or directory)"

Answer (score 0):

At this time, this is a known issue. See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37609 for more details. Sadly there is no official fix yet. But in that RSP you will find a workaround by Michael Geddes that might help you:

> For those that want to get going no matter what, I suspect this will work (haven't tried it yet, and it will probably not survive an update):

```
Install Python 2.7 package from python.org
Disable SIP
    Reboot Mac hold down Command + R
    From a shell:
        > csrutil disable
        > reboot
Remount / as read-write
    > sudo mount -uw /
Check that /System/Library/Frameworks doesn't exist and then Copy (?link) in the Python framework.
    > cp -R /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework /System/Library/Frameworks
Enable SIP
    Reboot Mac, hold down Command + R
    From a shell:
        > csrutil enable
        > reboot
```

Comment: Thank you, it can be a solution, I try ...

Comment: Meanwhile a patch has been released for 11.1. And guess what? It does not fix the problem, merely issues a workaround similar to this. https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-11-1-alexandria-patch-1-available/

Comment: the solution isn't valid, Monterey have the root folder like a Virtual foolder and encrypted, it's impossible change the folder.

Comment: The good solution is recompile PAServer librarys to find Python in /library/Frameworks/.. folder, the problem is that my subscription to embarcadero is down and I can't download new PAServer. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, followed the link posted by Sherlock70 to the link posted (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37609)

I saw part way down in the comments that Marco Cantu posted saying the patch was available and had this link on his post https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-11-1-alexandria-patch-1-available/

Once I ran the RadStudio 11.1 patch, I copied the new PAServer 22.0 over to my Mac and followed the "Additional Steps for Python Configuration on macOS" that Marco has in his post above.

Once I did that, everything is able to run on my iPad running iOS 15.4.1 now

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the steps in the linked Embo blog. Using Montery. It still returns the error about not being able to find the System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python path etc.
Stupid thing was working yesterday.

Have just reinstalled Delphi 11.1 and the two patches on GetIt (so version is now Embarcadero® Delphi 11 Version 28.0.44500.8973)

Installed Python 2.7 on the Mac and ran the 3 commands in the terminal.

This is beyond frustrating ....

Comment: Finally got it to work. Had to reinstall PAServer, aand then re run the 3 command lines ...
Be warned, follow the steps exactly: